# JQuery Datepicker DateFormat is not parsing day

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Never seen this issue before, very strange! Basically I have a simple datepicker:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The StartDate field is required." id="StartDate" name="StartDate" readonly="True" type="text" value="12/12/2013 00:00:00" />

<script>
$("#StartDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
</script>
```

But when I pick a date, it appears in the text box in the format '2013-12-dd'. Anybody seen this problem before?

EDIT

Here is the code that is generating the html input element:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.StartDate, new {@readonly=true})
```

Comment: Why are you giving value in different format like `value="12/12/2013 00:00:00"`? (Not sure if that matters or not, though.)

Comment: That's asp.net inserting a raw datetime. Possibly the problem? i was going to change afterwards but I'll change it now and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Try putting `type="date"` instead of text. And check if you are facing [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12865237/1777090) issue

Comment: That completely broke it :(

Comment: @EllyReed Remove the dateformat in datepicker.  Just leave `$("#StartDate").datepicker();`.  Let see whats happens in you envir and then try to figure out.

Comment: Thanks Praveen - I have removed and now it's showing '12/dd/2013'

Comment: @EllyReed seems weird.  Is value is generated by other code?  means generating date dynamically?  if possible share the whole code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, updating jquery ui to 1.10.3 fixed it.

I was previously using a combination of jquery 1.7.1 and jquery ui 1.8.11.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code :

The HTML :

```
<input type="text" id="StartDate" value="2013-12-12" />
```

The Javascript :

```
$("#StartDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9kB2g/1).

Comment: I've updated my code to use: <input type="text" id="StartDate" value="2013-12-12" /> but still the same result

Answer (score 0):

Here is [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/6U7JW/1/) of your code. In the text box all is fine.

Comment: Very weird. There must be something else at play.